# Building a Rascal Node via Java Method

Tags: rascal

I am using Antlr4 to parse Python code and have successfully been able to generate a ParseTree. How do I build a Rascal node via a Java method that can be used within my Rascal script? (Any resources will be appreciated)

Comment: There's python-air on the cwi-swat GitHub organization. Maybe that could be an alternative?

Comment: Otherwise I'd look at some example code. The flybytes library has clean code that maps JVM bytecode to rascal datatypes, written in java.

Comment: I have looked at python-air it's fine but it doesn't really work well with my code base(requiring python, it doesn't seem to work seamlessly across OS), currently in my setup I have been able to get the ParseTree, I just want to know if there's a way to build a rascal node with Java like it's done in Rascal. That being said I will look at the flybytes library and see if it solves my problem.

Comment: flybytes contains code examples for what you want indeed. It's a matter of using TypeFactory and IValueFactory to create Rascal values.

Comment: Thanks, I have decided to keep the Antlr4 as an alternative, for now I am using the python-air project, but I noticed an issue, python decorators are not parsed into the Rascal AST(ADT) is there a way around that or does it need a code fix

Comment: that would need a fix indeed!

Comment: When will that be resolved? :-)

Comment: first step would be an issue report on the code repo in github. then we can start planning for the feature request. Do you have time to start such an issue?

Comment: I would get at it as soon as possible

Comment: I just did that :-) https://github.com/cwi-swat/python-air/issues/11

Comment: Hello @jurgen, the `python-air` issue hasn't yet been attended to, and the issue has been opened, I will really appreciate if it gets resolved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @pius-arhanbhunde; python-air-0.0.4 was released today with a fix for your issue. Thanks for reporting and for the patience.

Comment: When I ran the code I get, `running external Python parser failed on <content>`, I suspected that the code wasn't picking up the python interpreter, so I replaced `loc pythonBin = exists(|PATH:///python3|) ? |PATH:///python3| : |PATH:///python|;` with `loc pythonBin = |file:///usr/local/bin/python3|;` it works, but I will assume the former was to generalize sort the hardcoded directory in the code. But why does it work in my machine? @jurgen

Comment: My code assumes the python interpreter is on the Unix search PATH for the system process that spawns the JVM that runs the rascal interpreter. It's possible that the VScode LSP client (an instance of node.js) does not have your specific path for python. That might explain it.

Comment: Thanks for the response any suggestion on how to resolve it

Comment: If you start code from a (bash) commandline terminal it will probably just work. If you start it from a icon on the desktop, you will need to configure the PATH variable for that kind of interaction to include `/usr/local/bin`. That really depends on the OS you are using.